# Can I install Lubuntu without having the admin password?

Tags: software-installation, lubuntu

I installed Ubuntu a few years ago on an old computer (Acer Aspire One, with no CD-ROM). Now I would like to change it to the latest version of Lubuntu but I do not remember my password for the computer. It is possible to install Lubuntu without the password to the computer? If yes, what would be the best way of doing this?

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/24024/253251) method  to reset forgotten password ?

Comment: If you're fine with wiping the HDD, just boot the install disc and go for it. If you need to backup the files first, it gets more complicated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. You don't need to remember old Ubuntu password to install new. You just boot a bootable CD/USB and wipe the partition belonging to old Ubuntu install and install Lubuntu on it.

If you still want to reset the password check this question

- [How do I reset a lost administrative password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password?noredirect=1&lq=1)

To create bootable USB from ISO check this question

- [How can I create a Windows bootable USB stick using Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/289559/how-can-i-create-a-windows-bootable-usb-stick-using-ubuntu)

Check these for installation help

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/InstallingLubuntu
- [How do I install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)